# eclipse editor, how to work with text editor (theme) when working with a specific perspective?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, themes, perspective

Is there a way to change the 'Appearance color' (or theme) in the editor when choosing to work with a specific view/perspective?

To be more specific, I'm starting to use python and I wish to have a different theme but when switching to Java I'd like to use the default editor.

Doable?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to make the theme depend on the perspective, I believe.

The straightforward solution would be installing a Python plugin, which then has its own editor (and own syntax highlighting settings). You would have to do that for every file type, nonetheless.

Apart from that, your best choice is probably the [Eclipse Colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html) plugin, which can do syntax coloring based on the file type.

(Disclaimer: I've never used any of those myself).